# $X$ is an independent random variable from any other random variable then $X$ has to be a constant.

Tags: probability-theory, independence

I had to show that the constant random variable is independent of any other random variable.

Now I'm looking if $X$ is an independent random variable from any other random variable then $X$ has to be a constant.

Is the following proof correct?

Edit: I have developed a little my proof but am still unsure if it is enough to show what is asked

$F_{X,X}(x,x)=\mathbb{P}(X \leq x, X \leq x) = \mathbb{P}(X \in A, X \in A)= \mathbb{P}(X \in A) \cdot \mathbb{P}(X \in A)$

$=[\mathbb{P}(X \in A)]^2 = F_{X}(x) \cdot F_{X}(x)$

Therefore, $\mathbb{P}(X \leq x)=0$ or $\mathbb{P}(X \leq x)=1$

Hence, the event:

\begin{equation}
     (X \in A) = \left\{
        \begin{array}{ll}
   1      & \mathrm{if\ } x \in A \\
   0     & \mathrm{if\ } x \notin A
        \end{array}
      \right.
   \end{equation}

then

\begin{equation}
     (X \leq x) = \left\{
        \begin{array}{ll}
   \emptyset      & \mathrm{if\ } X < x \\
   \Omega     & \mathrm{if\ } x \ge X
        \end{array}
      \right.
   \end{equation}

and therefore, $X$ is a constant

Comment: Could you provide more context, notice that you are using the same random variable $X$.

Comment: I was suggested before to prove X is independent of itself for this proposition. However, I am unsure if this is the procedure needed to prove so.

Comment: You have started the solutioin correctly but where is the proof that $X$ is a constant?

Comment: I was thinking about arguing that could happen only if the probability is 0 or 1, but then I'm not sure how to continue :(

Answer (score 0):

If you're interested in an other solution,
try consider the random variable $Y:=$ arctan$(X)$ and notice that var$(Y) = 0$, what can you conclude  ?

Comment: It can not be dependent. Thanks, but I believe I would need to do the respective integrals and since there is not any density defined for $X$, I can not determine $Var(X)$